# Data Cut off when exporting to excel in SQL Reporting Services 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I am having huge lines data which could accomdate in Textbox.

While I am exporting to excel the wrapping up of data occurs and the data
is being cut off.

When i manually change the textbox height i can see the full data but i need the full data to be 
displayed in the first time itself.

Comment: any update on this i need this quick...

Comment: Please do the needfull.. I need this immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your report layout, set the **CanGrow** property of the Textbox to **True**.